# Excluding directory from Perforce

Tags: perforce

If I checkin a codebase into perforce, what is the proper way to exclude dirs? I've noticed that deleting the folder from the workspace excludes it from the depot, but is this the proper way?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If the directories that you want to exclude should not be version controlled at all, then the proper thing to do is [delete](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/delete.html) those directories, which will remove them from the repository.

If those directories do belong in source control, and you just want to exclude them explicitly from your workspace, you can do that by editing your workspace view. For example:

```
//depot/... //my-workspace/...
-//depot/folder-to-remove/... //my-workspace/folder-to-remove/...
```

That will exclude `folder-to-remove` and all its subdirectories from your workspace.

Comment: Is this possible with clients using streams? When I added a minus expression to my `View:` section, it seemed to disappear next time I did `p4 client`. In a stream-ish world, do I need to make a virtual stream in order to exclude directories?

Comment: Yes, to the best of my knowledge you would need to make a virtual stream to exclude directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the initial checkin, you can mark the entire directory structure for add, but before you checkin, type the following

`p4 revert directory_to_remove/...`.

Other than that, as you and @Mike pointed out, a `p4 delete` or workspace exclusion would be fine.